# changing strings in pd.df using apply in order to do pd.eval()

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pd.df looking like this:

```
            open    high    low     close               
2007-01-02  107155  107250  107150  107185
2007-01-03  107195  107310  107170  107245
```

the values strings need to be changed as follows:
`pd.eval(x[:3] + '+' + x[3:] + '/320')`

So the open on 2007-01-02 is: 107.484375

This works on individual values and I can apply it on one column at a time too but struggling to apply this to the entire df.

Grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easyly without eval:

```
def fun(x):
    a,b = divmod(int(x), 1000)
    return a + b / 320

df.applymap(fun)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [df.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to perform your operation on the elements of dataframe.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: pd.eval(str(x)[:3] + '+' + str(x)[3:] + '/320'))
```

Incase your columns are of object dtype (i.e. strings) then you can remove the str() call in the above code.

**NOTE**: This will work if the values are not NaN.